# How to get number of days for next month?

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

Given a date, how do I get the number of days in the next month? So, if the original date is in December it should give 31(January), in January 28/29 (February), etc.

Comment: How do you know whether is it s leap year when you have only the month?

Comment: please provide an example code of what you are trying to do

Comment: I do have column with date. But here what I do: I get number of month of date in column, I add +1 to this number so basically it's next month, and I want to get number of days in this month.  I'm using extract ( month from p_date) + 1

Comment: So, rather than breaking this down into an unanswerable question, why not present the *whole* problem - given a *date* (not just a month number), you want to determine the number of days in the following month. *That*s an answerable question.

Comment: Read this and retry [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the number of days in next month? Use `ADD_MONTHS()` to get that. Use `LAST_DAY()` to establish the last day of the month. `EXTRACT()` the DAY from that to give the number of days.

Today is in April, so how many days are then in May?

```
SQL> select sysdate
  2         , extract(day from (last_day(add_months(sysdate, 1)))) days_next_month
  3  from dual
  4  /

SYSDATE   DAYS_NEXT_MONTH
--------- ---------------
19-APR-16              31

SQL>
```

Oracle has a wealth of date functions. We can chain them together to achieve virtually any calendrical calculation our heart desires. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions002.htm#SQLRF51179).

Comment: Yes, sir! That's what I was need. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

if you have a date column you can obtain the LAST_DAY and CAST as an INT

```
SELECT CAST(to_char(LAST_DAY(your_date_column),'dd') AS INT)
FROM your_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have `month` and `year` to get number of days in that month

```
select extract(day from (last_day(to_date('2016/02/01','yyyy/MM/dd'))) ) from dual;
```